# Refresh view background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am adding `refreshcontrol` to `tableview` this way, but background color of view is white. How can I set it default? Thanks.

```
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

[image]

**UPD:** Also it doesn't work smoothly.

Comment: Are you sure this is all a refreshControl background and not the tableView's superview color ?

Comment: tableview's superview color is shown there, lightgray

Comment: use `refreshControl.backgroundColor` wont help?

Comment: did help, thanks, but i have some issue. one minute, ill update the question.

Comment: @Tj3n, no, it doesnt help

Comment: i used it to change the refreshcontrol background, not working for u or something?

Comment: Use the View Hierarchy Debugger in Xcode to find out what view is actually white, then set its background color appropriately. The button is next to the other debug/breakpoint buttons above the debug console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code is inside a UITableviewController, you don't have to add a subview. UITableViewControllers have a `refreshControl` property, so you can just set

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

If you've done this, the background color should be the same as your tableView's background color. If you want a different color you can use

```
self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines

```
refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() // or any other color you want
```